# Accuracy of math.pow, numpy.power, numpy.float_power, pow and ** in python

Tags: python, math, floating-accuracy

Is there are difference in accuracy between math.pow, numpy.power, numpy.float_power, pow() and  ** in python, between two floating point numbers x,y?
I assume x is very close to 1, and y is large.

Answer (score 1):

One way in which you would lose precision in all cases is if you are computing a small number (z say) and then computing

```
p = pow( 1.0+z, y)
```

The problem is that doubles have around 16 significant figures, so if z is say 1e-8, in forming 1.0+z you will lose half of those figures. Worse, if z is smaller than 1e-16, 1.0+z will be exactly 1.

You can get round this by using the numpy function log1p. This computes the log of its argument plus one, without actually adding 1 to its argument, so not losing precision.

You can compute p above as

```
   p = exp( log1p(z)*y)
```

which will eliminate the loss of precision due to calculating 1+z

Comment: Thanks!
Is it better than taking the number base 2 instead of e-based?
I am asking because I think that log2 is more accurate then log1p.

Comment: I don't think there is a log21p (that would calculate log2(1+p). So probably best to use log1p